# How long should it take to process 15GB of logfile data on Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I have a cluster with 1 Master (m4.large), 6 Core (m4.large), and 4 Task (m4.large) nodes. The 15GB of cloudfront log data splits into 35 mappers and 64 reducers. Currently, it's taking more than 30 minutes to process fully -- too long for my purposes, so I stop the job to reconfigure.

How long would I expect the processing to take with this setup? What would be a reasonable resizing to get the job to run in under 15 minutes?

Comment: Where is the data located? In S3 or HDFS?

Comment: Initially on S3, but then moved to hdfs without much success